# Netplan, cloud-init and Ubuntu Mate

Tags: mate, netplan, cloud-init

I'm a novice with Ubuntu, and especially Ubuntu Mate that I have installed and have been using for a month now on a Raspberry PI 4 8GB.

My issue is using static IP address configurations.

Everything worked fine when using WiFi.

I used the NetworkManager GUi available in Ubuntu Mate to disable DHCP, switch off Wifi and configure a static IP address, netmask, gateway and dns srv.

Mate ignored everything I configured until I learned that we have to use netplan.

So I tried that too. The configs were still NOT persistent although I could force the IP addr with ifconfig once logged on.

Reading up on netplan which I hadn't encountered before, I learned about the yaml files it uses, on my machine the only that existed looked like this

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                driver: bcmgenet smsc95xx lan78xx
            optional: true
            set-name: eth0
    version: 2
```

So THIS then seemed to be overriding anything I put in nnmcli/NetworkManager
So I researched further leading me to this

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: false
            addresses: [192.XXXXXXX/24]
            gateway4: 192.XXXXXXXX
            nameservers: 
              addresses: [XXXXXXX]
```

with commands "netplan try" then "netplan apply". This became persistent after a reboot.

My question is do IP addresses etc HAVE to be hard coded in this file like this?
If I change parameters in Network Manager GUI will they take effect or not?

If I delete everything after "renderer:NetworkManager" in the yaml file will that mean it will use the configuration I can see in the NM GUI / nmcli listing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu Mate...

Your **/etc/network/interfaces** should look like this...

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Your ONLY **/etc/netplan/*.yaml** file should look like this...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Create this file... **/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg** with the following content...

```
network: {config: disabled}
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Then use the NetworkManager GUI to configure your eth0 wired connection for a static IP (if that's what you want/need)...

[image]

Comment: Thanks heynnema for this, I'll try it out soon. 
A qucik question though. Does the network configuration then get initialized immediately on boot or ONLY after a login session has started?
I need it to do the former i.e. use my config at boot regardless of any user session

Comment: Oh and my interfaces file looks like this
     # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
     # Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
     source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
The interfaces.d directory is empty

Comment: @franglais73 I believe the network config gets initialized at boot, as long as it's set to auto-connect. Your /etc/network/interfaces file is fine.

Comment: @franglais73 Status please...

Comment: @franglais73 Status please...

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply.
My Raspberry PI with Ubuntu Mate now boots up with a correct ethernet configuration using the IP address I want.
However the /etc/networks/interfaces file doesn't look like your suggestion.
It had a commented line and a new line like this 
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d

Comment: The latter is a directory and it contains numerous other directories if-down.d, if-up.d, if-pre-down.d, if-pre-up.d each having numerous files. !!
/etc/netplan contains 2 files 50-cloud-init.yaml & originam.yaml
Strange.

Comment: So I'm NOT stuck anymore but I don't know how to interpret these settings, what put them there, thus how to edit them nor what will happen if I implement what you suggest.

Comment: @franglais73  Is this a Mate desktop installation, or a Server installation with a Mate GUI installed? Edit your question and show me BOTH .yaml files from /etc/netplan. Your /etc/network/interfaces shouldn't have the include statement commented out.

Comment: Its Ubuntu Mate on Ubuntu 20.04 workstation on a Raspberry PI v4

Comment: @franglais73 You haven't shown me the two .yaml files that you see in /etc/netplan.

Comment: 50-cloud-init.yaml contains
his file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: false
            addresses: [192.168.1.121/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.254
            nameservers: 
              addresses: [192.168.1.254]

Comment: @franglais73 For textual data, it's best to copy/paste the output as an edit to your original question. After pasting the text, select the pasted text, and click the {} icon to format it into human-readable format. Please show me BOTH .yaml files.

Comment: The other is afile called originam-yaml 
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}

Comment: network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: no
            addresses: [192.168.1.121/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.254
            nameservers: 
              addresses: [192.168.1.254]
            match:
                driver: bcmgenet smsc95xx lan78xx
            optional: true
            set-name: eth0

Comment: Sorry this comments feature isnt the best top share content

Comment: @franglais73 That's correct. Don't use the comments for large amounts of textual data/output. Edit your original question, as I specified in my comment 5 minutes ago.